# Slider on homepage only

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I would like to get the slider to only show on the homepage of a WordPress site. Do I edit this slider.php?

```
    <!--Slider START-->  
<div class="slider"><?php putRevSlider("home") ?></div>
<div class="slide-container">
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="orange2">
<div class="txt-12">AQUALIFT PACIFIC</div>
<div class="txt-13">Aqualift Pacific Pty Ltd has evolved from the original Potable diving operation formed in 1997 to inspect and maintain water storage structures.</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--Slider END-->
```

Comment: no, you need to call module in just home.php if you don't want it on blog posts remove module from blog template.php (file names do vary as per theme)

Comment: @karan: -infinity for `u`. Don't be lazy. Using `u` indicates an IQ somewhere below absolute zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
    <!--Slider START-->  
  <div class="slider"><?php putRevSlider("home") ?></div>
  <div class="slide-container">
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="orange2">
  <div class="txt-12">AQUALIFT PACIFIC</div>
  <div class="txt-13">Aqualift Pacific Pty Ltd has evolved from the original Potable diving operation formed in 1997 to inspect and maintain water storage structures.</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!--Slider END-->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: **+1** Was *just* about to post this